Can I remove files and folders from .git/refs/remotes/origin without breaking things?
I am cleaning up my git repo and after I have run git prune I still have a bunch of refs in .git/refs/remotes/origin. None of these refs are "mine", meaning that I did not create the branches and I have never done git checkout [branch name] on these.
How did they end up there? Can I remove them without breaking anything?
Also, the folders that are present, specifically the numbered ones and the one called amanerik, how did they get there, and can they be removed?


What is the intent of this "clean up"?

In general, DO NOT edit the contents of .git/ directly.
Those are remote tracking branches. Specifically they track the remote named origin, which is usually where you cloned from.
Git is a distributed version control system, which means there's no central server. Each repository is complete. Git keeps track of the state of other repositories, such as your origin. When you git fetch origin (or git pull origin which does a git fetch origin), Git uses these remote tracking branches to remember what commit each branch on the remote was at.
Each file is the name of a branch on the remote. If there's a / in the remote name then it goes in a subdirectory; the amanerik directory means there's a remote branch called amanerik/something.
The files contain nothing more than a commit id; that's all a branch is, a name and a commit id. Normally there's little cost to these remote branches, because they share your local history. However, since your remote has a prodigious number of branches it may be bloating your repository size by adding a lot of commits your local branches do not reference.
By default, Git does not remove tracking branches which have been deleted on the remote. Try pruning them with git fetch -p. This may eliminate most of the remote branches. You can make this the default, which I recommend. Those dead remote branches may have been keeping a lot of otherwise unreachable commits alive.
You can claw back some disk space by running git gc. It should remove the individual files and replace them with a more efficient packfile. Plus it will do other work to clean up your repository.
Finally, if you don't want to push and pull with your origin repository again, delete the remote. git remote rm origin. You can always add the remote back later.

If there's enough of them that the sheer number of short files bothers you, say
git pack-refs --all

They're remote-tracking refs, they show the state of branch tips at that origin as of the last time your repo talked with the origin repo.
The folders hold multiple branches that start with the folder name and a /.
